# Truncate an NSString to width

Tags: objective-c, ios, algorithm

I'm trying to convert the [code found here](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/cocoa/truncate-an-nsstring-and-append-an-ellipsis-respecting-the-font-size.html) to a binary algorithm instead, since the linear method is terribly slow. I have a working implementation, but theres seems to be some thing I'm missing, since the results I'm getting are not precise (that is, if I add or subtract 20 or so pixels from the width, I get the same truncated string..it should be a little more accurate and have a closer cut):

```
-(NSString*)stringByTruncatingToWidth:(CGFloat)width withFont:(UIFont*)font addQuotes:(BOOL)addQuotes
{
    int min = 0, max = self.length, mid;
    while (min < max) {
        mid = (min+max)/2;

        NSString *currentString = [self substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(min, mid - min)];
        CGSize currentSize = [currentString sizeWithFont:font];

        if (currentSize.width < width){
            min = mid + 1;
        } else if (currentSize.width > width) {
            max = mid - 1;
        } else {
            min = mid;
            break;
        }
    }
    return [self substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, min)];
}
```

Can anyone see off the bat what could be wrong with that? (This is a category method, so `self` is an NSString.

Comment: Why do you need to calculate this yourself? What are you doing with the string? If you are only showing it inside a label then you can configure the label to truncate it for you. You can even allow the label to shrink the font size a little to be able to fit the text to prevent truncation.

Comment: I'm drawing it and need to add an ellipses at the end of it. I also want to wrap quotes around it, so the drawInRect withLineBreakMode is not an option here, since it would cut off the end quote..

Comment: Thx dude for your link above.. I searched for my problem solution like crazy but finally found it in your post..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this line is wrong:

```
[self substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(min, mid - min)];
```

This means that every pass, you're only examining the size of the string from `min` to `mid` -- that's not the string that you're going to end up displaying, though, because `min` is marching up the string as you search. You should be always be testing starting from the beginning of the string:

```
[self substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, mid)];
```

which is what you're going to return when your search is done.

Comment: Ah yes this was the problem! Thanks!

Comment: Note that `[string substringToIndex:mid]` will save you the step of creating an NSRange.